# How to install Mono XSP as a daemon on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, mono

I want XSP to run on my virtual Debian 5 as a daemon.

How can I do that?

I tried next:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/xsp
```

updated the script properly:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Mono XSP4"
NAME=xsp4
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--port 80 --nonstop --root /home/godfather/Projects/Test"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
```

then:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d xsp defaults
```

But after system restart it becomes stuck on next:

```
xsp
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/godfather/Projects/Test
Listening on port: 80 (non-secure)
```

That's all.

It has the same output if run it in user mode and without `--nonstop`:

```
xsp
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/godfather/Projects/Test
Listening on port: 80 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

Is it XSP bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start-stop-daemon` should be appended with `--background`

Answer (score 1):

XSP isn't supposed to be used in production, it's a development server.

For production, take a look at mod_mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Comment: In fact, in your case Apache will handle user requests and anyway via mod_mono will redirect them to XSP: `The module passes off requests for ASP.NET pages to an external program, mod-mono-server, which actually handles the requests`

Answer (score 1):

Command to start as deamon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mono-xsp4 start
```

you might need to configure **/etc/xsp4/debian.webapp**

like this:

```
<apps>
  <web-application>
    <name>test</name>
    <vpath>/test</vpath>
    <path>/var/www/xsp4</path>
  </web-application>
</apps>
```

you can this configuration file manualy or use command: `sudo mono-xsp4-admin --path:/realPath`

you can restart:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mono-xsp4 restart
```